(datastructure)Binary heap delete min big theta time question
In binary heap, these time complexities are given for the delete-min operation:

best: Θ(1)
average: Θ(log)
amortised: Θ(log)
worst: Θ(log)

I don't understand the best case: Θ(1)
Do we have to think of the case where the heap has just 2 elements?
Could you give me an example of a best case?

What is your source for these time complexities?

Obviously the best case is when the heap has 1 <= n <= 3 elements. In such a case, Θ(1) = Θ(log ).
